# validar valores iguales en un formulario con jquery o js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que si el valor esta duplicado me lo resalte o lo borre,
El formulario es

```
                                Numero de CUPS:
                            </th>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <div id="divcup">
                                    <div class="form-group" style="display:flex;">
                                        <input type="text" name="cups[]" id="cups1" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero del CUPS" onblur="obtenerEstSec(this)" style="width:30%" required/>
                                        <input type="text" name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion1" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripción" style="width:70%" readonly/>
                                        <input type="button" class="add_button btn-primary" value="CUPS adicionales"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
```

Y creo los campos adicionales con una funcion query

```
    var maxField = 10;
    var addButton = $('.add_button');
    var wrapper = $('#divcup');
    var x = 1;
    var y = 1;
    $(addButton).click(function(){
        if(x < maxField){
            y++;
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group" style="display:flex;">'+
                                    '<input type="text" name="cups[]" id="cups'+y+'" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero del CUPS" onblur="obtenerEstSec(this)" style="width:30%" required/>'+
                                    '<input type="text" name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion'+y+'" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripción" style="width:70%" readonly/>'+
                                    '<input type="button" class="remove_button btn-danger" value="Remover CUPS"/>'+
                                '</div>');
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });
});
```

Intente con una funcionn utilizando el queryAllSelector pero no se como hacer la comparacion o si es posible llamarlos por clase, pero igual no tengo ni idea de como compararlos
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con jQuery tendrías que recorrer todos los campos de que quieras comparar usando el metodo each(), te permite recorrer los input de una clase especifica por ejemplo

```
var array_todos_valores[];
$('.clase_de_numero_diferente').each(function(index) {
    var aqui_tienes_el_valor = $(this).val();

    array_todos_valores[index] = aqui_tienes_el_valor; 
})
```

/*  Luego de tener todos los elementos en un array usas el típico algoritmo de descarte de elementos en un array  */

```
var x = [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,7]
var uniqs = x.filter(function(item, index, array) {
  return array.indexOf(item) === index;
})
console.log(uniqs); // [ 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
```

Adaptas el anterior ejemplo a recorrer el array y eliminar los que no se repiten identificándolos con el id de su elementos que seria algún tipo de contador como id='3' o 1 o el valor id que mas fácil te sea trabajar